# Selenium Python script has different behavior on Windows and Ubuntu environments

Tags: python, windows, selenium, ubuntu, webdriver

I've tried running a script on Windows and on Ubuntu, both using Python 3 and the latest versions of geckodriver, resulting in differing behavior.  The full script is given below.

I'm trying to get the data for several different tests from a test prep site. There are different subjects, each of which has a specialization, each of which has a practice-test, each of which has several questions.  The `scrape` function walks through the steps to get data of each type.

```
subject <--- specialization <---- practice-test *------ question
```

The `get_questions` function is where the difference shows up:

- In Windows, it behaves as expected.  After the last question's choice is clicked, it goes on to a results page.
- In Ubuntu, when a choice is clicked on the last question, it reloads the last question and keeps clicking the same choice and reloading the same question.

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  import pathlib
  import time
  import json
  import os

  driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="./geckodriver.exe")
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
  data=[]

  def setup():

     driver.get('https://www.varsitytutors.com/practice-tests')
     try:
        go_away_1= driver.find_element_by_class_name("ub-emb-iframe")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", go_away_1)
        go_away_2= driver.find_element_by_class_name("ub-emb-iframe-wrapper")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", go_away_2)
        go_away_3= driver.find_element_by_class_name("ub-emb-visible")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", go_away_3)
     except:
        pass

  def get_subjects(subs=[]):
     subject_clickables_xpath="/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div/*/div[@data-subject]/div[1]"
     subject_clickables=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(subject_clickables_xpath)
     subject_names=map(lambda x : x.find_element_by_xpath('..').get_attribute('data-subject'), subject_clickables)
     subject_pairs=zip(subject_names, subject_clickables)
     return subject_pairs

  def get_specializations(subject):

     specialization_clickables_xpath="//div//div[@data-subject='"+subject+"']/following-sibling::div//div[@class='public_problem_set']//a[contains(.,'Practice Tests')]"
     specialization_names_xpath="//div//div[@data-subject='"+subject+"']/following-sibling::div//div[@class='public_problem_set']//a[contains(.,'Practice Tests')]/../.."
     specialization_names=map(lambda x : x.get_attribute('data-subject'), driver.find_elements_by_xpath(specialization_names_xpath))
     specialization_clickables = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(specialization_clickables_xpath)
     specialization_pairs=zip(specialization_names, specialization_clickables)
     return specialization_pairs

  def get_practices(subject, specialization):
     practice_clickables_xpath="/html/body/div[3]/div[8]/div[3]/*/div[1]/a[1]"
     practice_names_xpath="//*/h3[@class='subject_header']"
     lengths_xpath="/html/body/div[3]/div[8]/div[3]/*/div[2]"
     lengths=map(lambda x : x.text, driver.find_elements_by_xpath(lengths_xpath))
     print(lengths)
     practice_names=map(lambda x : x.text, driver.find_elements_by_xpath(practice_names_xpath))
     practice_clickables = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(practice_clickables_xpath)
     practice_pairs=zip(practice_names, practice_clickables)
     return practice_pairs

  def remove_popup():
     try:

        button=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[contains(.,'No Thanks')]")))
        button.location_once_scrolled_into_view
        button.click()
     except:
        print('could not find the popup')

  def get_questions(subject, specialization, practice):
     remove_popup()
     questions=[]
     current_question=None
     while True:
        question={}
        try:
           WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[7]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")))
           question_number=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[7]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]').text.replace('.','')
           question_pre=driver.find_element_by_class_name('question_pre')
           question_body=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[7]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/p')
           answer_choices=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('question_row')
           answers=map(lambda x : x.text, answer_choices)
           question['id']=question_number
           question['pre']=question_pre.text
           question['body']=question_body.text
           question['answers']=list(answers)
           questions.append(question)
           choice=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.test_button")))
           driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", choice[3])
           time.sleep(3)
        except Exception as e:
           if 'results' in driver.current_url:
              driver.get(driver.current_url.replace('http://', 'https://'))
              # last question has been answered; record results
              remove_popup()
              pathlib.Path('data/'+subject+'/'+specialization).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
              with open('data/'+subject+'/'+specialization+'/questions.json', 'w') as outfile:
                 json.dump(list(questions), outfile)
                 break
           else:
              driver.get(driver.current_url.replace('http://', 'https://'))
     return questions


  def scrape():
     setup()
     subjects=get_subjects()
     for subject_name, subject_clickable in subjects:
        subject={}
        subject['name']=subject_name
        subject['specializations']=[]
        subject_clickable.click()
        subject_url=driver.current_url.replace('http://', 'https://')
        specializations=get_specializations(subject_name)
        for specialization_name, specialization_clickable in specializations:
           specialization={}
           specialization['name']=specialization_name
           specialization['practices']=[]
           specialization_clickable.click()
           specialization_url=driver.current_url.replace('http://', 'https://')
           practices=get_practices(subject_name, specialization_name)
           for practice_name, practice_clickable in practices:
              practice={}
              practice['name']=practice_name
              practice_clickable.click()
              questions=get_questions(subject_name, specialization_name, practice_name)
              practice['questions']=questions
              driver.get(specialization_url)
           driver.get(subject_url)
        data.append(subject)
     print(data)
  scrape()
  ```

Can anyone help me figure out what may be causing this?

Comment: In the part ```driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", choice[3])```. Arguments could be incremental and I couldn't get what is ```choice[3]```. BTW, Is your JRE versions same in both envoriment?

Comment: @furkanayd choice[3] is just an arbitrary choice.  I'm trying to extract the data, so it doesn't matter which choice I provide, as long as I get to the next question.

Comment: @furkanayd  I'm using Selenium python -- isn't JRE only relevant to Java?

Comment: Sorry, It was JVM not JRE. Your browers uses JVM to compile webpages. When JVM versions are different pages may act differently.

Comment: I see that you have an 'except' condition that "if 'results' in driver.current_url" would not print out the error received. It looks possible that you're getting some kind of exception on the last question and you keep retrying it due to the while loop. Can you try making sure you print the exception at that point?

Comment: @CognizantApe  I tried handling the exception and printing it out but instead of an exception coming up at the last question, the while loop simply keeps executing with no apparent errors.

Comment: Did you try to play with HTTP headers that indicates browser and operating system you're using? Maybe webserver returns slightly different pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just timing. The last question will take much longer than the 3 second sleep until it loads the next page. Waiting for the page to be gone fixes this and speeds up the script execution.

```
  from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
<snip>
             choice=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.test_button")))
             choice[3].click()
             try:
                while choice[3].is_displayed():
                   time.sleep(1)
             except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
                continue
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem here is that you are using an Exception to break the loop. The proper way is to use a condition test, for example if result not in url, continue the loop, else, break the loop. The Exception can come in as a backup execution step.

The second is that just using sleep to wait for the results page is not enough, you need to test for the presence of an element on the result page. Or you could just watch for the title change:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.title_contains("Results"))
```